# Moment JS in typescript all methods fail as '[method] does not exist on type 'hooks'

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I have the moment.d.ts.  It is in my global.d.ts. ex:

```
import * as MOMENT from 'moment';
MOMENT(new Date()).format('L')
```

results in:

[image]

Comment: What is type `hooks`?

Comment: its something in the moment.js file

Comment: so, here's some irony:  the following works just fine:`Moment.locale('en-US')`; but the next line `_dateRangeControl.endDate = Moment(_now).add(_endInterval, 'M').format('YYYY-MM-DD');` dies with the hooks error not having 'add' as a method.....UGH.

Comment: ..its chaining that breaks it.  `let _m:Moment = Moment(new Date()); _m.format('L');`  works perfectly too...